# Using forms and checkboxlists in Yii

Tags: php, yii, checkboxlist

Am trying to wrap my head around using checkboxlists in the yii framework.

Example:
With the dropdownlist I can

```
<?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'fathercattle',array(1=>Yours,2=>Mine,3=>Nobody)); ?>
```

How do I get a similar effect using the Yii checkboxlists option?The values will be stored and retrieved in a database field as an array?

Secondly how do I get to format it?

Answer (score 6):

You use the checkboxlist in much the same way as the dropdownlist. Take a look at the [activecheckboxlist reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeCheckBoxList-detail). Also, if you want the data to come from the DB you can use the function [CHtml::listData](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) to transform an array of active records into a data array for the activecheckbox.

In regards to your second question, you can format the checkboxlist using the htmlOptions array. Two useful options are:

- template: string, specifies how each checkbox is rendered. Defaults to "{input} {label}", where "{input}" will be replaced by the generated check box input tag while "{label}" be replaced by the corresponding check box label.
- labelOptions: array, specifies the additional HTML attributes to be rendered for every label tag in the list. This option has been available since version 1.0.10.